Make backticks electric for markdown mode
I'm trying to use electric pair mode for backticks in markdown mode. The following code hasn't worked and throws and error whenever I type a backtick. How was it wrong?
(defvar markdown-electric-pairs '((?\` . ?\`)) "Electric pairs for markdown-mode.")
(defun markdown-add-electric-pairs ()
  (setq-local electric-pair-pairs (append electric-pair-pairs markdown-electric-pairs))
  (setq-local electric-pair-text-pairs electric-pair-pairs))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook (lambda ()
                (pandoc-mode t)
                (markdown-add-electric-pairs)))

The error is

Wrong type argument: commandp, electric-pair


You're not showing enough code. You don't show any use of function electric-pair. Set debug-on-error to t and show the backtrace, or show where you use function electric-pair. You're apparently trying to invoke it as a command. (Is there even a function named electric-pair?

Maybe you wanted to say M-x electric-pair-mode? FWIW, that works for me (after I (require 'elec-pair), load the above file and turn on electric-pair-mode in the buffer).

If you use Emacs' "Easy Customization" via M-x customize-group and then type or select electricity you can add your own pairs under the heading "Electric Pair Pairs." Note that you will have to set it and/or save it for future sessions. It will also show you the saved lisp expression for the setting, which is helpful in general.
If you want to set/change a custom variable in elisp,  use the macro setopt instead of setq as setopt runs any behind the scenes code set up on the variable. As a bonus, it defaults to setq behavior for non-custom variables.
I have learned to be aware of the difference between regular variables and customizable variables. If you setq or setq-local a customizable variable, it may (very likely) not work, or not work exactly how you intended. This is because additional setup code is run for custom variables.
More info:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Examining.html

You are correct about the additional setup in general, but these two (electric-pair-pairs and electric-pair-text-pairs) don't have any additional setup, so the OP's original code should work. I believe that he made a mistake (calling the non-existent electric-pair function, instead of electric-pair-mode) - see my comment under the question.

I see what you are saying. Whatever search leads them here is better served by your answer.
I have been a reader of SE for years, but not an answerer. What's the process? I can edit my answer, vote it down? I will check the help docs. Your guidance is appreciated.

No, no, no - your answer is fine (and the OP accepted it, so it must have worked for them). My comment is just a (small) clarification: one doesn't have to go the full customize way in this particular case, but in general, it is safer to do it the way you describe.
